# Boolean Algebra Function

Tags: function, boolean, decode, implements

> Implement the following Boolean function with Decoder and external logic gates as necessary. Draw the logic diagram and label all input and output lines.
>
> F = XYZ + (X' + Z')

I am having trouble converting the Function above to K-maps. I believe once i understand that, I will be able to finish my problem on my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parenthesis are not necessary, since 'or' is associative, so we have:

```
F = XYZ + X' + Z'
```

So the K-map would look something like:

```
    XY  XY' X'Y X'Y'
   +---+---+---+---+
Z  |   |   |   |   |
   +---+---+---+---+
Z' |   |   |   |   |
   +---+---+---+---+
```

We start out with the `XYZ` term, which occupies only one square since it fixes the value of all three variables:

```
    XY  XY' X'Y X'Y'
   +---+---+---+---+
Z  | T |   |   |   |
   +---+---+---+---+
Z' |   |   |   |   |
   +---+---+---+---+
```

Then `X'` touches one half of the table:

```
    XY  XY' X'Y X'Y'
   +---+---+---+---+
Z  | T |   | T | T |
   +---+---+---+---+
Z' |   |   | T | T |
   +---+---+---+---+
```

And finally `Z'` touches the bottom row, and only `XY'Z` is left as false:

```
    XY  XY' X'Y X'Y'
   +---+---+---+---+
Z  | T | F | T | T |
   +---+---+---+---+
Z' | T | T | T | T |
   +---+---+---+---+
```